# PWA for Magento2 - best option now?

Tags: magento2, javascript, pwa

We would like to develop a PWA storefront with **[Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)**. Vue Storefront for Magento 2 doesn't utilize Nuxt.js and it will be many months (or longer) before *Vue Storefront **Next*** (the version built with Nuxt.js) supports Magento.

Some options we have seen include:

- https://vuefront.com/
- https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/ (not a store front out of the box)
- <strike>Magento Studio PWA</strike> - not a Nuxt.js dev framework
- <strike>Vue Storefront for Magento 2</strike> - not a Nuxt.js dev framework

VueFront looks interesting, but it appears to be a much smaller project than Vue Storefont. Any thoughts on it?

Are there other Nuxt.js options we should consider?

BTW, our store is very non-standard. We cannot use Vue Storefront without heavy customization.

What is our best path for developing a Magento PWA frontend in Nuxt.js at this time? Our timeline dictates that we have to start development now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ScandiPWA** `https://github.com/scandipwa/scandipwa-base` to develop PWA store.

You can install pre-build PWA theme `https://github.com/scandipwa/base-theme`

Installation details here `https://docs.scandipwa.com/docs/installation/on-existing-m2/`

Currently **ScandiPWA** support magento 2.3.x except 2.3.4.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not based on Nuxt.js. 

> ScandiPWA is based on React and utilizes GraphQL API of Magento 2.3.